# How to position div at absolute position?

Tags: html, positioning, absolute

I'm trying to move my div in exact place (in pixels) I want (coordinates should be relative to parent's div).

I've tried to write this:

```
<body>
    <div id="desk" style="position: absolute; width:400; height:400; background-color:blue;" >
        <div id="cell1" style="position: absolute; left: 51px; top: 1px; width: 48px; height: 48px; color:black; background-color:black;" />
        <div id="cell2" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 51px; width: 48px; height: 48px; color:black; background-color:black;" />
    </div>
</body>
```

Here are two squares in (51,1) and (1,51) coordinates.

I've expected to get this:

[image: expected]

but got this:

[image]

Why? What I'm doing wrong and how it can be made properly?

P.S. 'fixed' instead 'absolute' will do the job, but squares are positioned not under parent div and does not respond to scrolling. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Browser -- chromium-browser, ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<div id="desk" style="position: relative; width:400px; height:400px; background-color:blue;" >
    <div id="cell1" style="position: absolute; left: 51px; top: 1px; width: 48px; height: 48px; color:black; background-color:black;"></div>
    <div id="cell2" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 51px; width: 48px; height: 48px; color:black; background-color:black;" ></div>
</div>
```

1. Close `<div>` tags. It thinks, that the 2-nd div is the child of the 1-st.
2. Use px in `width:400px; height:400px;`

Comment: "Make the blue div position: relative" — To be a containing block the position property needs to be set to something that isn't "static". It is "absolute" so there is no need to change it to "relative".

Answer (score 2):

You left the end tags off your divs, so `cell2` is inside `cell1` and thus is positioned with respect to the edges of `cell1` and not `desk`.

You cannot use XML self-closing tag syntax in HTML.

Answer (score 2):

You need to close your DIV tags properly:

```
<body>
    <div id="desk" style="position: absolute; width:400; height:400; background-color:blue;" >
        <div id="cell1" style="position: absolute; left: 51px; top: 1px; width: 48px; height: 48px; color:black; background-color:black;"></div>
        <div id="cell2" style="position: absolute; left: 1px; top: 51px; width: 48px; height: 48px; color:black; background-color:black;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7za4f/)

Comment: Thank you, that is. I'm writing _html_, not _xhtml_, and I've forgot it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GvQ3x/

Close your `div` (`<div></div>` instead of `<div />`) tags, also use `px` (or anything else) when you want to set your container div size